# Is there a mouse shortcut in Google Chrome to reopen last closed tab?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, tabs

I know I can use the keyboard shortcut to reopen the last closed tab, but is there a mouse based method?

It would be really handy. If I remember right, you used to be able to middle click on the tab bar to reopen tabs, but that got removed in later versions of Chrome, who knows why.

An extension that offers that behaviour would be awesome.

Comment: What is the keyboard shortcut? I know the mouse shortcut is right-clicking a tab and choosing `Reopen closed tab`. Aaah. I already see. Ctrl+Shift+T.

Comment: I was looking to do exactly this. [AutoControl Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol-shortcut-mana/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd) is the perfect extension for this. It lets you create all sorts of mouse shortcuts, gestures, combinations of buttons, wheels etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mouse gesture extensions who can do this. For example [Smooth Gestures](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smooth-gestures/lfkgmnnajiljnolcgolmmgnecgldgeld)

Under the options tab, you are looking for *Undo close tab*. You can choose between a Keyboard Shortcut, a Scroll Gesture, Mouse gesture or a Rocker Gesture to assign it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oh that sounds good, I'll give that extension a try.  Thanks!